# SpringBoot Application Context error: : Kotlin, Gradle,Database, Docker Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, kotlin, compiler-errors

I wanted to setup a connection between my postgresql database, which is inside a docker container and my Project.
The Docker an everything is set up via a **docker compose file** which looks like this:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
db:
  container_name: postgres_container
  image: postgres
  restart: always
  environment:
    POSTGRES_DB: postgres_db
    POSTGRES_USER: admin
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
    PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  volumes:
 - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

pgadmin:
  container_name: pgadmin4_container
  image: dpage/pgadmin4:5.5
  restart: always
  environment:
    PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
    PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: secret
    PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 80
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
  volumes:
    - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
  links:
    - "db:pgsql-server"
volumes:
 db-data:
 pgadmin-data:
```

My Project is supposed to be written in Kotlin an I have set up **Spring Boot** with the **initializer**, which looked like following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAQvH.png)

I have added the following into the **application properties** file to get a connection to the database.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres_db
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=secret
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

This is my `main` file:

```
package com.nosiaj.nstudycloud

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication

@SpringBootApplication
class NstudycloudApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<NstudycloudApplication>(*args)
}
```

And I wanted to create a table via code

```
package com.nosiaj.nstudycloud.entity

import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.Table

@Table(name="customer")
@Entity
class Customer {
   @Id

   private var uId: String = TODO("initialize me")

   private val firstName: String

   private val lastName: String

   private val email: String

   private val phone: String

   private val IBAN: String
```

}

This is my **build.gradle.kts** file:

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.12.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.6.21"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.6.21"
}

group = "com.nosiaj"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Now when I start the application it connects to the database and creates the table, but I still get Error and the server stops. This is the **Output**:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.2)

2022-08-07 16:54:22.736  INFO 55209 --- [           main] c.n.n.NstudycloudApplicationKt           : Starting NstudycloudApplicationKt using Java 17.0.4 on simba-desktop with PID 55209 (/home/simba/Dokumente/Project/nstudycloud/nstudycloud/build/classes/kotlin/main started by simba in /home/simba/Dokumente/Project/nstudycloud/nstudycloud)
2022-08-07 16:54:22.739  INFO 55209 --- [           main] c.n.n.NstudycloudApplicationKt           : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-08-07 16:54:23.342  INFO 55209 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-08-07 16:54:23.359  INFO 55209 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 3 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-08-07 16:54:23.743  INFO 55209 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-08-07 16:54:23.750  INFO 55209 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-08-07 16:54:23.751  INFO 55209 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
2022-08-07 16:54:23.812  INFO 55209 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-08-07 16:54:23.812  INFO 55209 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1026 ms
2022-08-07 16:54:23.949  INFO 55209 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-08-07 16:54:23.991  INFO 55209 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.10.Final
2022-08-07 16:54:24.110  INFO 55209 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-08-07 16:54:24.182  INFO 55209 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-08-07 16:54:24.286  INFO 55209 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-08-07 16:54:24.298  INFO 55209 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2022-08-07 16:54:24.594  INFO 55209 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-08-07 16:54:24.602  INFO 55209 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-08-07 16:54:24.635  WARN 55209 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-08-07 16:54:24.928  WARN 55209 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
2022-08-07 16:54:24.930  INFO 55209 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-08-07 16:54:24.932  INFO 55209 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-08-07 16:54:24.938  INFO 55209 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2022-08-07 16:54:24.943  INFO 55209 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-08-07 16:54:24.955  INFO 55209 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-08-07 16:54:24.975 ERROR 55209 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at com.nosiaj.nstudycloud.NstudycloudApplicationKt.main(NstudycloudApplication.kt:13) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:229) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:43) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:238) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:282) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:213) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1077) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:234) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Die Adresse wird bereits verwendet
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:555) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.netBind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:337) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:294) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:275) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1313) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:614) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1074) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    ... 20 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

So why does this Error appear? And how can I solve it ? I don't know what I am doing wrong, if someone could help me, that would be really great !!

Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

It means another process is running on same port, so you have to kill it.

First, list which app using which that port and get it's pid

`lsof -i:8080`

Then kill it with

`kill <pid>`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Sir!
I looked up the processes which were running, with your command and there are two processes running. They seem to be from my docker compose. The good news: When I kill both of them, I can run my application. The bad news: When I try to enter pgAdmin via the browser with localhost:8080, I can't reach the website anymore. It shows me a whitelabel Error Page.  How can I access it ? 
Sorry for my questions, Im quite new to this :S